# How to change formatting of Parameter "Type In" option in Tableau?

Tags: date, tableau-api

When Tableau is switched to having the Parameter filter as "Type In", it automatically changes the format of the Parameter from January 1, 2020 to 1/1/2020 12:00:00 AM. However, this gives the illusion the user can type in the date by the second when I simply generate only days behind the scenes, each at 12:00:00 AM. So if a user types it by the hour they get back the date they typed at 12:00:00 AM. How can I ensure the "Type In" parameter option stays as MM DD, YYYY format -which is what the parameter is?

Below, I've left the End Date parameter (formatted just like Start Date parameter) as the slider version to show the format I'd like in Start Date's Type In feature.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the data type of the parameter to Date instead of Date/Time